# C# preprocessor-like protection

Tags: c#, c-preprocessor

I was wondering either it is possible to create a rule in C# inside the code, that will prevent from "compiling" and print an error message of my choice. For example:

Let's say:

- I have a method that takes as an argument bytes vector.
- Inside that method I check what's the length of this byte vector.
- If it's too long, to short etc I would like to prevent the program from 
    compiling and print an error message in the Error list.

I know I could use assertion and stuff, but that is working on already compiled code.

Comment: No, you can't because it's a run-time check (you don't know array size at compile time and array size may/will change according to run-time conditions) so what you can do is to throw a run-time exception (or use assertion). Code contracts (and static analysis) may help you little bit with stuff like this but not in this case. IMO best thing for this is **unit testing**, it'll check run-time behavior you can't handle with static typing/checks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would answer NO because the compiler (at compilation time) can't know the value of the parameter at run time.

Have a nice day,

Alberto

**EDIT:**
Check the first comment to your question because it's a more complete answer compared to this one :)